# Selecting source code based on boolean

Tags: conditionals

Is there a way to select source code based on a boolean and not just select text to display.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newif\ifanswers
\answerstrue
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question This is the first question \\
        {\ifanswers 
            The first answer includes a graph. \\
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw circle (1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \question This is the second question \\
        {\ifanswers 
            This is the second answer is just words.
        }
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could do something like `\ifanswers now you see me \else now you don't \fi`. Of course you can drop the `\else` branch if you don't want that. For TeX it is indeed source code you select, it does not get to see the branch that is not executed. With `\answerstrue` `\ifanswers Hallo\else\foo\fi` doe not raise an error because `\foo` is undefined, while with `\answersfalse` it does.

Comment: `exam` class define a `solution` environment. You can put your answers inside it and show them using the class option `answers`.

Comment: You need a `\fi` even if you don't want to include an `\else...` branch.

Comment: Thanks cfr. Its sometimes the little things that are hardest to remember.

Answer (score 3):

`\if` must be ended with `\fi` even if no `\else` branch is wanted:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifanswers
\answerstrue
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question This is the first question \\
        {\ifanswers 
            The first answer includes a graph. \\
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw circle (1);
            \end{tikzpicture}\fi
        }
    \question This is the second question \\
        {\ifanswers 
            This is the second answer is just words.\fi
        }
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Note that this code does not require `ifthen`, though it does depend on `tikz`. Also, it is generally a Bad Idea to end lines with `\\`. However, I do not know the `exam` class well enough to say whether `questions` is an environment in which this is acceptable, so I have not changed it in the code above.

[image: answers]